# WebRequest.GetResponse() is getting an "underlying connection was closed"

Tags: network-programming, odata

I build the WebRequest object and then call GetResponse() on it. The url is "https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata".

And it comes up in a browser fine. What's really weird is these are returning a 200 so it should be good. But no data is coming back.

According to Fiddler there are two requests that go out:

**Request #1**

```
A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.1 (TLS/1.0)
Random: 5E 5B 1A 26 84 02 5A 4B DF 6B BF 22 DF 2C 03 AD 37 62 DA CE 05 79 7E B4 5C 58 AF BE 8C 26 5D CA
"Time": 4/4/1990 2:38:54 PM
SessionID: empty
Extensions: 
    server_name services.odata.org
    supported_groups    x25519 [0x1d], secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
    ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
    SessionTicket   empty
    extended_master_secret  empty
    renegotiation_info  00
Ciphers: 
    [C00A]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C009]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C014]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C013]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION
```

**Response #1**

[image]

**Request #2**

```
A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.1 (TLS/1.0)
Random: 5E 5B 1A 26 0D B0 9F BF 4F D8 FC 5D 27 47 A8 7C CB 83 2C 43 4C 2B C3 8A 0C C0 EB 30 3D 6E AB 51
"Time": 4/4/1990 2:38:54 PM
SessionID: empty
Extensions: 
    server_name services.odata.org
    supported_groups    x25519 [0x1d], secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
    ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
    SessionTicket   empty
    extended_master_secret  empty
    renegotiation_info  00
Ciphers: 
    [C00A]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C009]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C014]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C013]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION
```

**Response #2**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the TLS level. Just add:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```